# Avoiding "null-check" in List processing using Optional of Java 8

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, nullable, java-stream, option-type

In Class `Site`, I have two utility methods.

The first one, `parseStub`, parses a `Site` into a `Master` *if* no errors occur; otherwise, it returns `null`. Using `Optional`:

```
public static Optional<Master> parseStub(Site site) {
    // do some parse work; return Optional.empty() if the parse fails.
}
```

The second method `parseStubs` is to parse a list of `Site` into a list of `Master`. It reuses `parseStub`, and has to handle the possibly empty `Optional<Master>`:

```
public static List<Master> parseStubs(List<Site> sites) {
    return sites.stream()
            .<Master>map(site -> Site.parseStub(site).orElse(null))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

> Note that in the code above, I introduced `null` again.
>   How could I avoid `null` (and `filter(Objects::nonNull)`) using `Optional` consistently?

Comment: Java 9: `flatMap(site -> Site.parseStub(site).stream()).collect(toList())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
return sites.stream()
        .map(Site::parseStub)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```